# How to display edittext and softkeyboard over other views

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

This is simple my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="ir11.co.tsco.fll.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bear"
    android:text="Hello World!" />


<EditText
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:hint="Comment ..."
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

in manifest I have set this property for its activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

but when I touch edittext and softkeyboard appears, imageView resized!! or if I set the following property for its activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

softkeyboard will push imageView up!.

This is not what I want. I want edittext + softkeyboard come over ImageView without pushing imageview up or resizing it.

what should I do?

Comment: Put the relativelauoit within scroll view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this

`<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.so3.MainActivity">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="@drawable/bear"
         android:text="Hello World!" />
    </ScrollView>
    <EditText
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:hint="Comment ..."
    />
</RelativeLayout>`

and set android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in your manifest

Also in onCreate() of your activity add the following code:

```
ScrollView sv = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll);
    sv.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write below line in manifest inside activity tag:

```
  <activity ........................
             android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustNothing">
```